# ra ($31) register contain unaligned return address (MIPS)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, mips

I am trying to reproduce call stack on MIPS, for more details check my previous question: 
[How to get a call stack backtrace?(GCC,MIPS,no frame pointer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815650/how-to-get-a-call-stack-backtracegcc-mips-no-frame-pointer/45817238#45817238)
Since MIPS has no frame pointers, to do so I have to find the return addresses on the stack.
I have checked the ra register at the beginning of one of the functions(before it has been pushed to stack) and found out that it contains unaligned return address.

```
   ra = 0x*******5
```

Why could that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're linking for a microMIPS target (16-bit instructions, GCC option `-mmicromips`), perhaps?

Assuming this is correct, from the *[microMIPS GCC Toolchain Usage](https://doc.lagout.org/electronics/doc/mips/soft/MD00784-2B-umicroMIPS-APP-01.02.pdf)* document:

> To enable processors to determine the current ISA (MIPS32 ISA or
>   microMIPS ISA), the least-significant bit of an address (bit 0) is
>   utilized as the ISA mode bit (0 = MIPS32 ISA, 1 = microMIPS ISA). This
>   mechanism enables calls to microMIPS or MIPS32 functions via the JALR
>   instruction by setting a register value odd (for microMIPS) or even
>   (for MIPS32) from the address.

In this manner, functions compiled for microMIPS can call functions compiled for MIPS32, and vice-versa, by setting the low-order address of a function (or return address, jump target, etc.) to 0 for MIPS32 or 1 for microMIPS. Since all instructions are either 16-bit or 32-bit and must be aligned accordingly, to find the real return address, simply mask off the low bit.