# addiu instruction encoding (MIPS,GCC)

Tags: gcc, assembly, mips

Here is addiu instruction opcode (16-bit instructions, GCC option -mmicromips):

```
 full instruction: addiu sp,sp,-280
 opcode, hexa:     4F75         
 opcode, binary:   1001(instruction) 11101(sp is $29) 110101
```

My purpose is to detect all instruction of this kind (`addiu sp,sp,`)
and then to decode the immediate, in the above case (-280) (to follow the sp).
What I don't understand is the encoding of (-280).
Linked to: [How to get a call stack backtrace?(GCC,MIPS,no frame pointer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815650/how-to-get-a-call-stack-backtracegcc-mips-no-frame-pointer?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Not sure what kind of mips that is? 16 bit?

Comment: I am working with mips 32bit

Comment: That is certainly not 32 bit ... the mips32 machine code for that instruction is `27 BD FE E8` with `FE E8` being `-280`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it is a microMIPS instruction, compiled with  GCC option -mmicromips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

microMips has a specialized `ADDIUSP` instruction which the assembler chose to use. The first 6 bits are the opcode `010011`, the next 9 bits are the encoded immediate `110111010 = 0x1BA` and the LSB is reserved at `1`.

The encoding for the immediate uses scaling by 4 and sign extension. Given that `0x1BA = -70` (using 9 bits) the value is `-70 * 4 = -280`.