# $sp register does not change at the beginning of the function

Tags: gcc, assembly, mips, mips32, stack-pointer

Linked to: [How to get a call stack backtrace?(GCC,MIPS,no frame pointer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815650/how-to-get-a-call-stack-backtracegcc-mips-no-frame-pointer)
I am reproducing the call stack(more details at the link above) by iterating the function using the assembly code and user stack.
I have to find the previous $sp for each function, most of the functions start with the following instruction:

`addiu sp, sp, -80`

I can easily conclude the previous $sp from the opcode.
The problem is that I found functions that never changes the $sp even though they use the stack, it seems that the functions that call this kind of functions use the same activation frame on the stack In other words never change $sp.
How can I reproduce the previous $sp in this case?

Comment: I can only imagine those are nested functions. Anyway, if sp is not changed, then of course previous sp is equal to current, what do you want to find?

Comment: Each iteration I have to find previous sp and ra. The ra saved on user stack, I can conclude the offset of the ra from sp from the instruction that pushing the ra to user stack. That is the reason why I need sp each iteration.

Comment: You just have to find where $ra has been written, if $sp has not been changed and $ra has been saved relative to it, then where is the problem? If it's not been saved (leaf function) it's still in $ra.

Comment: The problem is that I have to find the previous function and I can not do that without the ra.

Comment: I don't understand. $ra is either still valid or it's stored somewhere that you know. You got an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen with optimized code.

If a leaf function only modifies the temporary registers, and returns to a return statement in its caller's code, then there is no need for `$ra` to be changed, and there is no need for a stack frame for that function. Example:

```
int caller(....) {
  int a, b, c;
  ...
  c = leaf(a,b);
  return c;
}
int leaf(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

See also [tail calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).